# Operation on characteristic polynomial and Jordan normal form

Tags: abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

This is given as part of showing the general Cayley-Hamilton theorem (so you shouldn't refer to Cayley-Hamilton in the proof).

Let $R$ be a ring, and $M$ a finitely-generated free $R$-module. Let $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ be an $R$-linear map, and $P_\phi(X)$ the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$. Suppose $R$ is an algebraically closed field.

Show that $P_\phi(\phi)=0$ by writing $\phi$ as a matrix in Jordan normal form.

Well, since $R$ is an algebraically closed field, all eigenvalues of $\phi$ lies in $R$, so the Jordan normal form exists. But what's the point of it then? I don't quite see.

Comment: Wow. $R$ jumps from "a ring" to "an algebraically closed field". The formulation is funny! 

You probably mean all eigenvalues of $\phi$, not of $M$.

Comment: You didn't need to put a bounty to ask me for more details! Just question me more, I'll be more than happy to detail the parts you didn't understand perfectly.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thanks, it is clear now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_k$ be the (distinct) roots of $\phi$ (by distinct, I mean that if they are not, I omit multiplicities). For instance, if a $4 \times 4$ matrix has characteristic polynomial $(x-2)^2(x-1)(x-3)$, then I would write $\lambda_1 = 1$, $\lambda_2 = 2$, $\lambda_3 = 3$.

Choose a basis for $M$, say $\{m_1,\cdots,m_n\}$ over which $\phi$ has Jordan normal form. (So two vectors for $\lambda_2$, one for $\lambda_1$ and one for $\lambda_3$.)

To each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, there is a Jordan block with $\lambda_i$'s on the diagonal and (possibly some) ones on the second diagonal. (For instance, the block corresponding to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3$ in my example has to be $(1)$ and $(3)$, but the block for $2$ could be either $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. )

In particular, if $m_{i_1}, \cdots, m_{i_{\ell}}$ are the vectors who span the subspace over which $\phi$ has Jordan block form with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, then if $\lambda_i$ has multiplicity $n_i$, we have
$$
(\phi - \lambda_i I)^{n_i}(m_{i_j}) = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad P_{\phi}(\phi)(m_{i_j}) = 0.
$$ 
(I implicitly used the fact that the matrix $A$ with $0$'s on the main diagonal and $1$'s in the second diagonal satisfies $A^{n_i} = 0$ where $n_i$ is the size of the block, which implies the $(\phi - \lambda_i I)^{n_i}(m_{i_j}) = 0$ part.) Note that the implication follows because $n_i$ is precisely the power of $(X - \lambda_i)$ which divides $P_{\phi}(X)$, so we can multiply $(\phi - \lambda_i I)^{n_i}$ by the missing factors of $P_{\phi}(\phi)$ to obtain the full polynomial.

This means that $P_{\phi}(\phi) (m_i) = 0$ for all $1 \le i \le n$, hence $P_{\phi}(\phi) = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why $(\phi-\lambda_i)^{n_i}(m_{i_j})=0$? I would agree if it's $(\phi-\lambda_iI)^{n_i}$, but here $\lambda_i$ is just a constant and we need to expand the polynomial first...

Comment: @JJ Beck : I thought it was clear that $\lambda$ subtracted to an endomorphism meant $\phi - \lambda_i I$. I just didn't bother to write it out. I'll edit if it pleases you. In the same way that you write $I$ for the identity map, you can write $\lambda$ for the "multiplication times $\lambda$" endomorphism. If you agree if it's $(\phi - \lambda_i I)^{n_i}$, then you agree. :)

Comment: @JJ Beck : Note for instance that if $P_{\phi}(X) = X^n - 1$, $P_{\phi}(\phi) = \phi^n - I$. This is because when we "plug in" the endomorphism $\phi$, we must also turn the coefficients of the polynomial into endomorphisms. We usually omit that conversion since the inclusion of $R$ into $\mathrm{End}_R(M,M)$ is canonical for any commutative unital ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$ ; we just send $1 \in R$ to $I \in \mathrm{End}_R(M,M)$.

Comment: I think the point may be that it suffices to prove the theorem for the polynomial ring Z[x1,…,xn2], and then one can form its field of fractions and take an algebraic closure. It's relatively easy to prove that over an algebraically closed field, any square matrix is similar to an upper triangular one, and then tha an upper triangular matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial ( which is easily computed in that special case). The full strength of Jordan normal form is not really needed.